# ItemsControl combobox selecteditem C# WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, mvvm

i have an application that when a button is pressed a new object "Category" is added , and the UI update inserting a ComboBox and a TextBlock :
[image]

if i press the button :
[image]m/DYQCN.png

if i press it again :
[image]

But when i select an item, each of the combobox changes :

[image]

How to avoid this ?

This is my code :

**XAML**

```
 <ItemsControl x:Name="icc" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Categorie,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >

                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                            <ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding c_nome_categoria , Mode=TwoWay}" Background="White" BorderBrush="Brown" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="150" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=icc, Path=DataContext.listaCategorie}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" DisplayMemberPath="nomeCategoria" ></ComboBox>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding contenutoCategoria}" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Inserisci gli oggetti" AcceptsReturn="True"></TextBox>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

            </ItemsControl>
```

ViewModel :

```
  private BindingList<Categoria> _listaCategorie = new BindingList<Categoria>();
        public BindingList<Categoria> listaCategorie
        {
            get { return _listaCategorie; }
            set
            {
                _listaCategorie = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("listaCategorie");
            }
        }

        private BindingList<CategorieValigia> _Categorie = new BindingList<CategorieValigia>(); 
        public BindingList<CategorieValigia> Categorie
        {
            get { return _Categorie; }
            set
            {
                _Categorie = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Categorie");
            }
        }

        public void InserisciCategoria()
        {
            listaCategorie = getCategorie();
            CategorieValigia cv = new CategorieValigia();
          
            Categorie.Add(cv);


        }
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to set `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem` to `false` in the XAML of your ItemTemplate.